# Совместимость гемов при обновлении ROR 4 на ROR 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gems, bundler

При обновлении rail4 до rails5 получаю ошибки совместимости гемов. На подобии следующей:

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "actionmailer":
  In Gemfile:
    devise_invitable (~> 1.7.0) was resolved to 1.7.4, which depends on
      actionmailer (>= 4.1.0)

    rails (~> 5.0.0) was resolved to 5.0.0, which depends on
      actionmailer (= 5.0.0)
```

Но `actionmailer (>= 4.1.0)` включает в себя `actionmailer (= 5.0.0)`. Или я не прав?

При создании нового RoR 5 приложения гем `devise_invitable` с рельсой не конфликтует.

Comment: "получаю ошибки" при выполнении какой именно команды?

Comment: **bundle update** или если удалить _Gemfile.lock_ то при **bundle install**.

Comment: Просто в том, что вы приложили, конфликта нет, AM 5.0.0 соответствует этим требованиям. Может, там просто было больше записей, а конфликт был с неуказанной?

Comment: Да. Вы правы. Спасибо!
_devise_invitable_ конфликтует с другими гемом.
Но почему отображается конфликт с _actionmailer_ непонятно.

Comment: И правда непонятно. `bundler` обновляли?

Comment: нет. просто в гемфайле обновил версию рельсы
_gem 'rails', '~> 5.0.0'_ и начал решать конфликты

Comment: А попробуйте. Возможно, баг в бандлере.